# Windows (Phone) Runtime Component stream between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I want to embed an existing C++ console application in my C# Windows Phone Gui application. I have already managed to convert the C++ console application to a Windows (Phone) runtime component allowing me to call it from C#. What I want to do know is route the original console output to a C# XAML console that I have already created for a similar application. My problem is that the C# console works with a class derived from "Stream" that uses the "Write" function to update itself with new text.

I unfortunately have now idea how I should create a stream that can be used by C# and C++ for my purposes. I have searched around but could not find an appropriate example.

If it makes a difference, the output does not have to be captured from the normal console output because the C++ application writes all its output to the console through a function called "log".

Comment: The phone has no console - are you simulating that in the UI somehow then?

Comment: Yes, I have my own console as mentioned above which uses stream...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to give the C++ a .NET callback that your C++ `log` function can use.

1. You should implement a WinRT interface with your `log` function in it (e.g. `ILog`).
2. Make sure that you create a C# class that implements this interface, and writes to your simulated Console.
3. As part of the app start up in .NET, create an instance of this class, and pass it down as an `ILog` object to C++ via WinRT.
4. Keep a copy of this interface around in C++ and use it inside your C++ `log` function.